# mysql join comma separated values

Tags: mysql, join

I have one table:

```
horse
    ->id
    ->course
    ->date
```

Another one:

```
course
    ->title
    ->trackstyle
```

And a third one

```
trackstyle
    ->id
    ->style
```

The style for the course can be multiple, so I thought I will create a field and save the value(s) delimited with a comma.

ie:

```
trackstyle
id:1
style:galloping

id:2
style:flat

course
title:ascot
trackstyle:1,2    (as it's galloping and flat)

title=beverley
trackstyle:1      (as it's just flat)
```

Now, I have trouble to build a request that will query all three tables ...

Is it the correct way to build my database?
Or should I just add a new column in my course table, where I will put the trackstyle in 'hard':

```
course
title: ascot
trackstyle: galloping, flat

title: beverley
trackstyle: flat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not a good way to build the Database. Instead you have to do something like following

```
course
    ->title

trackstyle
    ->id
    ->style
```

And one join table

```
 course_trackstyles
       ->course_id
       ->trackstyle_id
```

Your query will be something like following

```
SELECT c.title, GROUP_CONCAT(t.style) 
FROM course c JOIN course_trackstyles ct ON ct.course_id = c.id
              JOIN trackstyles t ON ct.trackstyle_id = t.id
GROUP BY c.title
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an one to many relationship because one course can have many trackstyles so:

```
course
title: ascot
trackstyle: 1
title: ascot
trackstyle: 2
title: beverley
trackstyle: 2

trackstyle
id: 1
style: galloping
id: 2
style: flat
```